# php return function exit point

Tags: php, function

The question is how to exit from function from nested function call? In other words:

```
function action() {
   // some working code
   KillingFunction();
   // code, that will not execute
}
```

In pseudocode, function might look like:

```
function KillingFunction() {
   return return;
}
```

Of course I can make:

```
function KillingFunction() {
   die();
}
```

But in such situation, all code that goes below action() will be dead.

Is there some kind of life hack for such situation?

Comment: Why do you need such functionality?

Comment: What about `break;`?

Comment: You can't do it. What if `KillingFunction()` was called from the top-level script instead of a function?

Comment: @MaveRick What about it? That's for exiting from loops or switches, it has nothing to do with functions.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? This seems like an XY problem. Maybe you should be throwing an error?

Comment: How about: `function killingFunction() { return false; } function action() { workingFunction(); if (!killingFunction()) { return; } }`

Comment: You stop a function using `return` (doesn't matter if it is `true` or `false`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check inner function returned value:

```
function main($terminate) {
    if (dieFunction($terminate)) {
        return false;
    }

    echo "Not dead too!";
    return true;
}

function dieFunction($terminate = true) {
   if ($terminate) {
      return false;
   }

   echo "I'm not dead!";
   return true;
}

main(true); // no output;
main(false); // "I'm not dead!Not dead too!"
```

You can apply different logic for returned values.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a function using `return`:

```
function action() {
  // some working code
  return 0;
  // code, that will not execute
}
```

Comment: I think he knows that. He wants to put something in `KillingFunction` that will force the caller to return immediately.

Comment: Hm. Then I wonder get why he wants to use `KillingFunction` at all..

Comment: Presumably it does some stuff, and then either returns normally or makes the caller return. It's not clear what the overall intent is, it seems like poor a poor linkage model.